# SharePoint Framework: Loading icon in property pane

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I wanted to show loading icon on the drop down present in property pane, till it does not get the data. I am unable to find what needs to be passed to in

```
this.context.statusRenderer.displayLoadingIndicator([Property pane reference], 'lists')
```

Any help/pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to this answer, but you can follow the below approach:

1) Create 2 private variables, `_listOptions` of type `IPropertyPaneDropdownOption` and `loadingIndicator` of type `boolean` (set it to **true**) in your base webpart class.

It would be somewhat as below:

```
export default class HelloWorldWebPartWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {

  private _listOptions: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption[];
  private loadingIndicator:boolean = true;
```

2) In your `getPropertyPaneConfiguration` method, there is a property named `showLoadingIndicator` of type boolean. Set this to the above defined `loadingIndicator` variable.

The method should look somewhat as below:

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {  
      showLoadingIndicator: this.loadingIndicator,    
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [              
                PropertyPaneDropdown('list', {
                  label: 'Select List',
                  options: this._listOptions                  
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

3) Now, we will populate the dropdown with dynamic values. For that we need to override the `onPropertyPaneConfigurationStart` method. I am using the list names as values, it could be any other REST API call returning JSON. Here, once the values are fetched, we will hide the `loading` indicator. The method is quite self explanatory.

```
protected onPropertyPaneConfigurationStart(): void {

    this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/Lists/?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Hidden ne true&$orderby Title`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      var options: Array<IPropertyPaneDropdownOption> = new Array<IPropertyPaneDropdownOption>();

      response.json().then((data) => {
          options.push( { key: "", text: "Select List" });
          data.value.forEach(list => {
              options.push( { key: list.Id, text: list.Title });
          });
          //since the returned values are pre-ordered, just return the list of lists
          this._listOptions = options;

          //set the loading indicator to false and render the property pane
          this.loadingIndicator = false;

          this.context.propertyPane.refresh();          
          this.render();

      });
    });
  }
```

End result :

[image]